# Cannot update Github key from CLI

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, git, github

I have only just tried to use github via `git` on the cli for the first time since they leaked their key and it needed resetting.

I added the new key into known_hosts under users/luke/.ssh (Windows 11) (didn't work so I removed all existing known hosts) and I also removed the known hosts them from the Registry (since Putty stores them there) but when I run any git command to github, it shows the warning about a new connection/signature and asks me "If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key...." but I cannot type anything at the prompt other than ctrl-C to cancel.

This is in the terminal window of VSCode but I tried the same in git bash and get the same problem: A prompt but entry is not accepted from the keyboard. I tried Powershell terminal but they all behave in the same way.

I can't think what might be wrong, never seen this before and the only other reference to it on StackOverflow said to run up some unamed GUI to modify the remote repository so I'm at a loss as to what I can do.

Please can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.

You can just open Putty (application) and connect to github:

- Host name: github.com
- Port: 22

Click "open" and then there will be a popover asking you to trust the connection, click "yes" and then git will work again!

Comment: Yes, I found it out under the "known issues" for Putty on Windows, although I can't say I ever seen it before.